# What kind of connector do I need to connect our outside tap

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

We have just moved into a new house and we have an outside tap thats not connected. There is a flexible pipe coming into the house from the outsite tap and a valve under the sink but how/what connector do I need to connect them together?

Many thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's where that leads? It's an odd configuration.

Comment: Yes it definitely is I have followed it outside and taken the outside tap off the wall to confirm.

Comment: Well, the lower image just shows a slip-on fitting for tubing. The upper one appears to show a garden hose connection. This is a scenario where visiting your local hardware store to see what they stock will be more fruitful than asking here. Arm yourself with accurate dimensional measurements.

Comment: Thanks, TBH I didnt know what to search for so even just you telling me its a slip-on fitting and a garden hose connection has helped me - Many thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't provide an answer, though, so feel free to post and accept one yourself. We can also wait for more experienced plumbers to do so. [Take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this site works.

Comment: what is the tap in top picture connected to?

Comment: Where you are in the world would help in general, but that logo is a John Guest speedfit fitting. You can see others behind in the picture. https://www.johnguest.com/speedfit/products/plumbing-fittings-home/plumbing-fittings/10-15-22-28mm-size-fittings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal pipe fitting at a bib is 3/4” inch here in the U.S.
So you would want a female but that looks like a hose fitting that requires a o ring or washer to seal. The outside one would use “poly” hose that slips into the opening and locks in place but I can’t even give a guess on the size from the photo. This is a bit of a hack setup although it may work I would want proper plumbing here especially going through a wall.